# Is an instance of HttpModule dedicated to a single IIS Request from beginning to end?

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, iis, httpmodule

I'm developing an HttpModule to capture logging and performance information for all requests to our web application. I'm tapping into the **PreRequestHandlerExecute** and **PostRequestHandlerExecute** events.

When my code executes within **PostRequestHandlerExecute**, is that code guaranteed to be executing within the same request context as the code which ran earlier on in **PreRequestHandlerExecute**? In other words, can I preserve state when handling the first event to be used during the execution of the second event?

Or is it possible for an HttpModule instance to service multiple concurrent requests, in which case any state necessary to connect the processing of these two events would need to be stored (and then fetched from) within the current HttpContext?

(I understand of course, that the HttpModule will be used to service multiple requests *sequentially* and that request-specific state from an earlier request will be irrelevant to a subsequent request. My question is specifically whether a single HttpModule can be used to handle multiple concurrent requests or whether I can rely on the fact that the HttpModule will be dedicated to a single request for the entire lifecycle of that request.)

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpapplication?source=recommendations&view=netframework-4.8#remarks "Instances of the HttpApplication class are created in the ASP.NET infrastructure, not by the user directly. One instance of the HttpApplication class is used to process many requests in its lifetime. However, it can process only one request at a time. Thus, member variables can be used to store per-request data." Your `HttpModule` instances are initialized by each `HttpApplication` instances, so use the hints to revise your understanding of IIS/ASP.NET internals.

Comment: @LexLi Thank you for that reference. I think I get it; if each HttpApplication instance processes one request from beginning to end, and each HttpModule is created by and dedicated to a specific HttpApplication instance, then it follows that a given HttpModule will process one request from beginning to end. So member variables can be set during processing of an earlier event, to be used subsequently in a later event. (Obviously, member variables need to be reinitialized in order to be useful for a subsequent request.) Thanks!

Comment: Correct. You can do more experiments to validate this. Maybe later post your own finding as an answer below and accept it. Good luck.

Comment: You are right. In a single request processing, there can be more than one modules which gets executed. HttpModules take part in processing of the request by handling the Application events.  Just like you say, a given HttpModule will process one request from beginning to end. More about [Application Life](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb470252(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: @LexLi - I have done some experimentation. I can see that an HttpModule is often invoked on a thread other than the one on which it was originally created. I've never seen an HttpModule interrupted while processing one request to service a second request. That being said, having not observed the phenomenon isn't necessarily proof that it cannot happen. So I am happy with the links you've both provided which confirm that I will be safe if during PreRequestHandlerExecute I accumulate state which will be used during PostRequestHandlerExecute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the literature, and borne out by my own implementation, an HttpModule instance is indeed dedicated to a single Http transaction for the complete Request/Response transaction lifecycle.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpapplication?source=recommendations&view=netframework-4.8#remarks

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb470252(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

State can be safely accumulated in one event to be used in subsequent events because all events the HttpModule instance will receive will belong to the same Request/Response transaction.

(Naturally, any accumulated state which is transaction-specific will need to be reinitialized for the subsequent transaction since an instance of an HttpModule is subject to be reused for a subsequent transaction once the current transaction has completed.)

I have furthermore seen that an instance of an HttpModule may be executing on a different thread than the thread on which it was originally created or previously executed.